# How to get first names of all persons in list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Get Values From a List of Dictionaries
Create a function `iterateDictionary2(key_name, some_list)` that, given a list of dictionaries and a key name, the function prints the value stored in that key for each dictionary. For example, `iterateDictionary2('first_name', students)` should output:

```
    Michael
    John
    Mark
    KB
```

And `iterateDictionary2('last_name', students)` should output:

```
    Jordan
    Rosales
    Guillen
    Tonel
```

Below is the given list of dictionaries.

```
`students = [
     {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
     {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
     {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
     {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
]`
```

I've tried particular targeting`print(students[0]['first_name'])` to at least show me where I am working in the list of dict but I am struggling accessing all dictionaries at once.

My code is unfinished because I'm struggling hard with this question.

```
def getValues(keyName, someList):
    for i in len(someList):


print(getValues('first_name', students))
```

I continue to get errors and I barely know where to begin.

Comment: `firstnames = map(lambda x: x['first_name'], students)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#students = [
#     {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
#     {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
#     {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
#     {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
#]

def iterateDictionary2(key_name, some_list):
    for d in some_list:
        print(d[key_name])


iterateDictionary2('first_name', students)
#Michael
#John
#Mark
#KB

iterateDictionary2('last_name', students)
#Jordan
#Rosales
#Guillen
#Tonel
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def iterateDictionary2(key_name, students):
    return [student[key_name] for student in students]
```

Then the output of calling the method for `('first_name', students)` will be a list of these values:
`['Michael', 'John', 'Mark', 'KB']`

Comment: The _assignment_ requires a function that prints all the values  corresponding to a specific key. You have posted the solution to a different problem...

Comment: Do you mean I have to print the values instead of using "return" statement? I assumed that is obvious and can be changed easily. Like: `print "\n".join([student[key_name] for student in students])`

Comment: I mean that the problem statement _requires_ a function that _prints_ the names, no more, no less.  In general your approach, to return a data structure, is more sensible and it's what I'd ask a student of mine to do, but...  (please don't overthink my remark, ciao)

Answer (score 0):

```
# method with two params a key and a  list
def iterateDictionary(key, students):
 for s in students:
    print(s[key])

# a list
students = [
     {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
     {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
     {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
     {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
]


# printing the first names
print("Printing First names ..")

# calling the method with a key (first_name) and a list    
iterateDictionary('first_name', students)

# printing the last names
print("Printing Last names ..")

# calling the method with a key (last_name) and a list
iterateDictionary('last_name', students)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Printing First names ..
Michael
John
Mark
KB
Printing Last names ..
Jordan
Rosales
Guillen
Tonel
```

**EDIT:**

If you want them printed in a list:

```
def iterateDictionary(key, students):
        print([s[key] for s in students])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Printing First names ..
['Michael', 'John', 'Mark', 'KB']
Printing Last names ..
['Jordan', 'Rosales', 'Guillen', 'Tonel']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_first_name_list(students):
    return [st['first_name'] for st in students if  'first_name' in st]
```

This will works, In this code checks the list of dictionary's has 'first_name' key , if dictionary has a 'first_name' key then the value of first_name appends in a list.
and list will be returns.